# CSS Flexbox - How to add a specific element after line break?

Tags: html, css

I have a flexbox components that on Desktop, it consists of 3 columns then it automatically breaks into a new line and adds another three columns.

eg

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item">column</column> 
  <div class="item">column</column> 
  <div class="item">column</column> 
    breaks
  <div class="item">column</column> 
  <div class="item">column</column> 
  <div class="item">column</column> 
    breaks
</div>
```

On smaller screens of course, it may only show 2x columns before breaking and on mobile it would only be 1 column.

Question is, is there a CSS only way to add an element (`<hr>` in my case) after each line break?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use media queries

Comment: would require scripting to add an element. The only thing you could do within CSS is the `:nth-child(3n+3)` pseudo-selector to add a pseudo-element with `::after`.

Comment: @John Shot how would you use media queries to add a `<hr>` element?

Comment: hr is not a bad idea, you can reset border and margin, then hide it on smaller résolution.

Answer (score 0):

here is a mediaquerie example :

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.breaks {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.item {
  border: solid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 30%;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {/* if hr to hide, do display:none in there */
  .item {
    min-width: 40%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .item {
    min-width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item">column</div>
  <div class="item">column</div>
  <div class="item">column</div>
  <!-- if hr stands here , display:none on small device -->
  <div class="item">column</div>
  <div class="item">column</div>
  <div class="item">column</div>
  <!-- if hr stands here , display:none on small device -->  
  <div class="item">column</div>
  <div class="item">column</div>
  <div class="item">column</div>
  <!-- if hr stands here , display:none on small device -->
  <div class="item">column</div>
  <div class="item">column</div>
  <div class="item">column</div>
 <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```